# elastic search logging configuration from java application

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to send logs into elastic search from my java application. What is best way to do other than using log4j ? is there a jar available which does it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Elasticsearch Java API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html

Comment: Thank you alpert. I do not want to do search .I want to push my logs so that it is available via KIBANA.

Comment: You can use Java Api to also push your logs inside your app.

Comment: Can you please help me in locating the java api for log push ?

Comment: You can use Index API:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html and Bulk API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-bulk.html to index documents.